# How can I get an html for to run a python script on submit?

Tags: python, html, cgi

I have an html form and I want to use python to send the information from the form to an sqlite database file. Right now I am trying to do it with cgi. I don't need anything fancy. Here is my code:

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample page to test fill_web_form.py</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p1><strong>SAMPLE PAGE TO TEST FILL_WEB_FORM.PY</strong></p1>

    <!--test form-->
    <form action="send_form_to_db.py" method="post">
        Form to be tested:<br>
        <input type="text" name="test_form"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

python:

```
# send_form_to_db.py

# sends data from html form to database

# import statements
import cgi
import sqlite3

cgitb.enable()

form = cg.FieldStorage()
data = form.getvalue('test-form')

conn = sqlite3.connect('sample.db')
conn.execute("INSERT INTO test_table [test_column] VALUES (data)")
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

When I run this the web browser doesn't run the python code, it just displays it as text.

Right now I'm just trying to do this in the simplest way possible without implementing things like Django.

Comment: Actually, django will be the simplest way possible :) Almost ;) 

Read here:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/basehttpserver.html
and here:
https://gist.github.com/UniIsland/3346170
and here:
https://docs.python.org/2/howto/webservers.html (but more than first two paragraphs)

Comment: @SebastianOpałczyński Django is definitely not the simplest way possible. That would probably be Flask.

Comment: The python code is meant to be run using python to act as a server. Don't open it in the browser. The browser is a client and does not run python.

Comment: This is a server configuration issue, not a Python question.

Comment: @AlexHall would Flask be simpler than cgi?

Comment: @AlexHall - yep, so I put the `Almost` there ;) Keeping flask in mind :)

Comment: Flask is extremely simple, is very popular, and has great documentation. I would recommend it. I cannot say for sure how it compares to cgi as I've never used that. But it is probably easier.

Comment: Framework is just a tool. Pick the right tool for your job :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Minor detail:  change `form = cg.FieldStorage()` to `form = cgi.FieldStorage()`.

*Note: i in cgi.*